# How to change Laravel/Vus Js axios base url after compiling to production

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs3

After compiling into production of my laravel/vue js app.I cannot be able to change the base url of axios from Laravel .env file. The App url will be different in my production environment from domain to domain so it will not be static. So I need something where i can change the app url without compiling the vue js app by passing the url in laravel .env file.

Here is my .env file of Laravel

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:+1UuTZrn8kYTWJGunXF4dxMoIwSIDfGMp8j4iQjkwgo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost/pos
MIX_APP_URL="${APP_URL}"


LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=medix_v4
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Here the axios setting that i am using

```
 const token = localStorage.getItem("store_token");
    if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    const API_URL = process.env.MIX_APP_URL;


    //axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost/pos/backend/';
    axios.defaults.baseURL = API_URL;

    // axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const options = {};
    //options.baseURL = config.SERVER_URL;
   // options.baseURL = '';
    options.timeout = 60000;
    options.params = {}; // do not remove this, its added to add params later in the config
    const instance = axios.create(options)
```

Comment: you can simply pass the base url as props rather than using from the env file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different versions of .env with names like `.env.local`, and `.env.production` if you want to compile for different versions. More details on: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#additional-environment-files

you need to pass `command --env=local` this way.

Or, you could also set up a deploy command on your server, whenever code is deployed run `num run prod` on the server, make sure you have the correct app URL on that .env of the production server.

Comment: The reason i cannot add 2 env files is because i dont know what could be the production url because i will send the source code to the multiple users the complied code. So i need  something where users can change there app url according to there servers url and users will not have dev environment where they can re compile the source code using npm run dev.